# What is the difference between "Ranks" and "Order" in this C code?

Tags: c, enums, typedef

```
typedef enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND} Order;
```

I'm not clear on what's going on here. It seems from the rest of the example in the tutorial that I would use `Order` to create variables, as in `Order x = 0;`, but what is `Ranks`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`Ranks` is the name of an **`enum`** and `Order` is the name of a `enum Ranks` **type**, when used you should do it this way

```
enum Ranks ranks;
Order      order;
```

it is similar to doing

```
enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND};
typedef enum Ranks Order;
```

Comment: More complete answer. +1

Comment: So essentially the line of code in my question creates two things simultaneously, an enum and a typedef'd alias to it?

Comment: @Aerovistae Yes exactly that. You can do the same with structs.

Comment: Is the only advantage of the typedef here that you don't have to write `enum` everytime you go to use it, you can just write `Order` instead of `enum Ranks`?

Comment: @Aerovistae You can define it like this too: `typedef enum {FIRST, SECOND} Order`.

Comment: Pretty much, but in my opinion it's not an advantage, it could easily destroy readability.

Comment: @FiddlingBits but you should mention that in that case, he woudldn't be able to use `enum Ranks ranks;`.

Answer (score 2):

`Ranks` is the name of the enum type, and `Order` is an alias of it - similar to:

```
typedef int Other_int_name
```

Answer (score 1):

A `struct`, `enum` and `union` can have both a tag and a `typedef` name. In

```
typedef enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND} Order;
```

`Ranks` is a tag and `Order` is `typedef`ed name.

In fact, tag and `typedef` name can even be same:

```
typedef enum Ranks {FIRST, SECOND} Ranks;   // Though, its not required
```